# cannot find DB connection info

Tags: php, laravel-5

I checked my config/database.php

I have:

```
 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

and in my connection I have:

```
 'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
```

but it seems that my DB configuration areh happening somewhere elese, I also defined my varioables in my .env file. But when I run the migrate in my app directory, it errors out :

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name
>   'usernam     e' (SQL: alter table `users` add `username` varchar(191)
>   null)

although I have already taken the migrate file for users out (renamed the php extension of it)

Any help will be appreciated.

edit: does thi happen that migration files are stored somewhere other than /database/migrations ?

Comment: Are you migrating? It says that your already have `username` column in the `users` table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error `duplicate column name 'username'` indicates the database has a table called `users` which has the column `username` in.

What seemed to happen: you took out the migration file out of Laravel before you did `php artisan migrate:rollback`. This left the database with all the schema structure that the migration wrote out. So obviously you can't run the same migration again because the same structure is already found in the database.

What you should do: log into your mysql server, drop, and create the database again.

1. `mysql -u root -p` then it will prompt you for the password of your mysql server.
2. `drop database your-db-name`
3. `create database your-db-name`

Then run the migrations again, `php artisan migrate`.

**Further diagnose method**

You can create a file 'database.sqlite' under the `/database/` folder and change your .env's `DB_CONNECTION` to `sqlite`.

Run migrations and rollback and run it again. If it messes up at any point, it means the migration files have got a problem in them.